# How to grow a Bootstrap element to fit remaining height without navbar?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to get the `#output` element to fill the dead space of the page, but all answers I found online suggest using `min-height: 100vh` in some way, but that doesn't take into account the navbar (copied from Bootstrap's website).

The final version should have the `<nav>`, the `.container` fit on the rest of the screen, and the `#output` within it taking the rest of the container space not taken by the `<img>` and `<div>` -- all in all, no overflow.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lfyh2bz9/1/

(Note: I know I should've delegated the style stuff into a separate CSS file, but I'm just trying to get it to work first :) )

How would you do this? Would you make the `<nav>` a `.container` and use `flexbox`? Would you convert the `.container` to `rem` units, like the `<nav>`? Or maybe calculate the remaining height using CSS?

Thanks in advance, --J.

Edit: even forcing the container items to be 25%-50%-25% (OR forcing the output to be 3 linebreaks high!) would work, assuming it's a percentage of the container itself!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it what you wanted to achieve? - [codepen](https://codepen.io/mazdok/pen/XWdWRMV?editors=1100)
(no changes in HTML, just a few new lines of CSS)

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar Title</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Page 1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Page 2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container-fluid d-flex flex-grow-1 flex-column" style="background: gray;">
  <div id="output" class="row d-flex flex-grow-1 justify-content-center text-center">
    <div>Stretch/Grow This Part To Fit Height Without Navbar And Rest of Content</div>
  </div>

  <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/381x298/O">
  </div>
  <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark col-4" onclick="">Option 1</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-light col-4" onclick="">Option 2</button>
  </div>

</div>

<style>
body {
  /*  expand body to fill page heigth  */
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Perfect! I'm looking through the changes now -- thank you!!

Comment: Is there a way to make the ```<img>``` the first one to shrink when needed (tbf, requires *extreme* close up)? I tried "flex-shrink" but no luck :\ (*just* missed the comment-editing window lol)

Comment: You can control how much flex element will shrink by a property - 'flex-shrink'. `flex-shrink: 0` means that element won't shrink. Bootstrap has a class for it `flex-sm-{shrink}-0`.  And some docs about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/flex-shrink)